# devenv command line doesn't build the whole solution

Tags: bash, devenv

We have a big solution with multiple project in it. It was created with 5 projects. All the 5 were always build successfully with Xamarin or devenv.

We developped another project outside the solution and then added it to the main solution. Now solution has 6 projects. In Xamarin, the whole solution builds. With devenv command, the last added project is not build.

My theory is that the place where the devenn command looks in the sln to know what to build is not the same as Xamarin, thus giving a different result.

Here is the command I use to trigger the build :

```
devenv /build "Debug|x86"  LibCS.sln
```

How can I make devenv build the last added project?

Comment: Can you show us how you are triggering the build with devenv? What does the script look like?

Comment: added it in my question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5 first project were configured with Visual Studio 2010.
The last (6th) project was configured with Visual Studio 2013.

The platform using devenv was building a solution (.sln) set for Visual Studio 2010, hence not recognising the 2013 project.